# how to answer incoming call in twilio API

Tags: twilio

how to answer in Twilio Api using answer button, i m unable to pick the call on browser,
i want to know how to answer or reject the call while i am connecting device on Answer button click, plz help me

my snippet is

```
Twilio.Device.setup('<?=$token?>');

Twilio.Device.ready(function(device) {
});

 Twilio.Device.incoming(function(conn) {
 $("#number").val(conn.parameters.From);
 var ss= "Incomging Call:\n"+conn.parameters.From; 
 $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
    // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
    conn.accept();

});



Twilio.Device.error(function(conn) {
alert("Error:\n"+data);
});

function call() {
    // get the phone number or client to connect the call to
  //  params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
   // Twilio.Device.connect(params);
  Twilio.Device.connect();
  }

  function hangup() {
    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
  }


 <input type="text" id="number" name="number"  />
 <button class="call" onclick="call();">
  Answer
</button>

<button class="hangup" onclick="hangup();">
  Reject
</button>
<div id="log">Loading app</div>
```

have any idea in twilio incoming call???

Answer (score 5):

Twilio evangelist here.

The code you've included above is automatically answering incoming calls because you are calling the `accept()` function in the *incoming* event callback.

If you want to change your app so that calls are only answered after a button is clicked, you will first need to add a second button to the UI.  In that buttons `click` event you call a function that calls the [`accept` function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#accept).

You can continue to use the incoming callback to do something like enable your accept button only when there is an incoming call, but notice that you'll need to create a global variable that holds the incoming connection so you can access it in the `accept` function.

```
var connection;

Twilio.Device.incoming(function(conn) {
    connection = conn;

    $("#number").val(conn.parameters.From);
    var ss= "Incomging Call:\n"+conn.parameters.From; 
    $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);

    //enable the accept button
    $(".accept").prop('disabled', false);
});

function accept() {
    connection.accept();
}

<button class="accept" onclick="accept();" disabled>Accept</button>
```

Of course you can get a lot more complex in the incoming function than whats shown above.  Check out [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/building-screen-pops-with-twilio-client-and-fullcontact-api.html) for a more complex example that shows how to use the jQuery dialog widget to show a screen pop.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I think priyanka may be having the same issue I am.  My client browser is indeed answering the call, but because of permissions issues regarding the microphone, the recipient still needs to take action to enable the micriphone.  It seems that only Chrome gives me any way to do this.  Firefox will if I actively click on the web page after the connection is made, but as the customer, I'd have no indication I need to do this.  In IE, there seems to be nothing I can do.  Is there any way to react to the incoming event with code that handles this?

Comment: Normally what I do in my demos is in the incoming function, I'll dynamically change the page to show a popup (or overlay, or similar UI) that lets the user know that there is an incoming call.  As part of that UI I also clearly show the user that they need to give the browser access to the microphone.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Is there a link to such a demo and/or sample code for that?

Comment: Updated my answer above with a link to a blog post that shows how to build a screen pop with the jQuery dialog widget.  You could easily extend this to also show some UI that prompts the user to accept the request for microphone access.

Comment: thanks i got it, code was right i have to give the incoming xml url in app url and outgoing in twilio url.